# Adding tool tip to CommandField ButtonType = "Link"

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to add a tool type to my command buttons on my gridview, but I am a bit stuck.

Here's the markup...

```
<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowEditButton="true" EditText="&#x21" ShowDeleteButton="true" DeleteText="&#x33;" CancelText="&#x4F" ItemStyle-CssClass="View1 View2 View3" ItemStyle-Width="45px" UpdateText="&#x50">
    <ControlStyle Font-Names="'WingDings 2'" ForeColor="Black" Font-Size="16px" />
</asp:CommandField>
```

When I breakpoint in code-behind and look at what is in `e.Row.Cells`, it is a collection of `DataControlLinkButton` but I cannot seem to find any reference to this in documentation to see if there's a `tooltip` I can set.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133902/how-to-add-a-tooltip-and-confirm-message-box-to-asp-commandfieldimage-button

Comment: I looked at that one @EdwindeKoning but that was where the ButtonType was an Image, not a Link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set it on `RowDataBound` of `Gridview`.

i am sharing a code snippet from one of my implementations.

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {                  
                if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit || e.Row.RowState.ToString() == "Alternate, Edit")
                {
                    foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
                    {
                        if (e.Row.Cells.GetCellIndex(cell) == 4)
                        {                                
                            ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton)(e.Row.Cells[4].Controls[2])).ToolTip = "Tooltip goes here";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception _e)
        {
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks... Bit silly of me not to realise that a DataControlLinkButton is actually a LinkButton :doh: